# Ansible Test what a Variable Begins with

Tags: ansible

I need to be able to install a MySQL library. Python has 1 package for v2 and another for v3. I need to be able to tell Ansible which package to install.

```
- name: Ensure MySQL-python is installed
  pip:
    name: MySQL-python
    state: present
  become: true
  when: python_version is regex("^2.*")

- name: Ensure mysqlclient is installed
  pip:
    name: mysqlclient
    state: present
  become: true
  when: python_version is regex("^3.*")
```

The regular expression is valid but Ansible is skipping them both even though this:

```
- debug:
    var: python_version
```

returns this:

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "python_version": "2.7.10"
}
```

Comment: Are you totally positively sure your `python_version` variable is set correctly in your playbook ? On my side (ansible 2.8.1) I cannot reproduce your problem and your regex match correctly. And why use a custom variable when you can get this automatically in your facts with `ansible_python_version` ? It would be much better to use version comparison (as proposed by @Vladimir Botka below). But this won't work either if your data is not correct in first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[regex](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) works for me with ansible 2.7.9. The example below

```yaml
      vars:
        python_version: "2.7.10"
      tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: Python version 2
          when: python_version is regex('^2.*')
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "Python version 2"
```

[Version Comparison](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) is more convenient for complex tests. The example below gives the same result.

```yaml
        - debug:
            msg: Python version 2
          when:
            - python_version is version('2', '>=')
            - python_version is version('3', '<')
```

---

The test `regex` is documented in [Ansible 2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) for the first time. In earlier versions, only the tests `search` and `match` are documented. In the current [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/test/core.py) the tests `search` and `match` are implemented on top of `regex`

```py
    def match(value, pattern='', ignorecase=False, multiline=False):
        return regex(value, pattern, ignorecase, multiline, 'match')

    def search(value, pattern='', ignorecase=False, multiline=False):
    ￼    return regex(value, pattern, ignorecase, multiline, 'search')
```

Comment: The regex in OPs example match correctly for me and are doing the job (ansible 2.8.1). So I suspect the problem is somewhere else. Meanwhile, I totally agree version comparison is the good practice solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Like Vladimir said.
Another improvement might be the source of `python_version`. When using `gather_facts` you can do it without regexp.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:

    - name: do some stuff
      debug:
        msg: do something because it is python 3
      when: ansible_facts.python.version.major is version('3', '=')

    - name: do other stuff
      debug:
        msg: I don't support legacy software
      when: ansible_facts.python.version.major is version('2', '=')
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you are in a virtualenv. ansible_facts.python.version reports the system python version rather than the version that's actually running ansible.